# Response.body() returns an object with null properties while using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

request is saying 200 response but in response body everything is null im new to retrofit . thanks

this is my reqeust call

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getString(R.string.FEED_BASE_URL))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    feed_api api = retrofit.create(feed_api.class);
    Map<String, String> feilds = new HashMap<>();
    feilds.put("param1",FEED_PROFILE_ID);
    feilds.put("param2",FEED_TOKEN);
    feilds.put("param3",decencrypted_id);

    retrofit2.Call<feed_model> call = api.get_single_post(feilds);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<feed_model>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<feed_model> call, Response<feed_model> response) {
         if(response.isSuccessful()){
             if(response.body()!=null)
             feed_list.add(response.body());
             else
                 Toast.makeText(single_post_screen.this, "This post don't exist any more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         social_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<feed_model> call, Throwable t) {
         Log.d("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",t.getMessage());
     }
 });
```

this is my api function

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("my_url/")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
})
Call<feed_model> get_single_post(@FieldMap Map<String,String> fields);
```

Comment: code 200 means that the request was successful. If your response.body is null, it means that server is not returning any body

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a logging interceptor to check that the server actually returns a body that is not null?

To do this, change your retrofit initialisation code to:

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(getString(R.string.FEED_BASE_URL))
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor()).build())
.build();
```

You should see your network request showing up in the logcat log in Android Studio.

Comment: it is saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $